# Must the shield be equipped for Gems to work in Infinity Blade 2?

Tags: ios, infinity-blade-2

I got a couple of gems on a shield but it is not equipped, will I still benefit from these gems even if I'm using a dual swords ?

Answer (score 1):

You will not benefit from the effect of any item without equipping it. You must equip the shield for it to work. Otherwise you could just stack gems on many items and gain a huge advantage.

Comment: I actually realised that you DO benefit from them. Use a heavy axe along with +HP on a shield, and you will realise that your stats change whether you're equipping it or not

Comment: @Render Wow, is that a glitch?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a shield for its work alone and not for Gems. You can equip any item without Gems. If you have a shield with 3 free places for Gems use *Lucky Wheel* to get rare gems and then the shield will help you much more than the normal shield.

Comment: Hi Big L, welcome to Arqade! Not to be rude, but I've just edited 3 of your posts in a row, do you think you can focus a bit more on your grammar and coherency?

Comment: well ok. sorry about that.

Comment: no problem :-), and again, welcome.